# iOS 9 custom animated wallpaper

Tags: ios, ios9

I want to create custom animated wallpapers for new iOS 9 SDK.

- Is there any way to create it by myself? I mean creating wallpaper from gif or video file, or maybe from frames.
- Can custom application install this wallpaper as a background, or insert it to phone library so user can set it as background by himself?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to accomplish this as yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something referencing this in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016572-DontLinkElementID_2).

I don't know so far if you'll be able to do exactly what you want, but you should definitely take a look at the link I provided.